# adds new columns to excel but with no values(only empty columns) pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

i have a dataframe and i want to add two new columns to them but it just adds names of the columns not with their value.  these are the name of the two new columns :   resultcellname , resultcellnamevalue

what is the problem?

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter
import openpyxl

v=int(input("how many periods do you have:\n"))
new_excel_by_user = str(input("Write the name of your new EXCEL file: "))
user_excel = pd.ExcelWriter(new_excel_by_user+'.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')


excelpathH = input("Insert your Excel path (HIGH): ")

excelpathH = excelpathH.replace('"', '')

dfH = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(excelpathH), engine='openpyxl')
dfH['resultcellname'] = ''
dfH['resultcellnamevalue'] = ''


cellname_columns = [col for col in dfH.columns if col.startswith('CellName') and 
not(col.endswith('value'))]
common_values = set(dfH[cellname_columns[0]])
for col in cellname_columns[0:]:

  common_values &= set(dfH[col])
  print(type(common_values))
  processed_values = set() # not to write the same result values again 
  line=0

  for index, row in dfH.iterrows():
    pairs = [(row.iloc[i], row.iloc[i + 1]) for i in range(0, len(row),2)]  # pairs of "cellname" and "cellnamevalue" and convert them to tuples

    for cellname, cellnamevalue in pairs:
     if cellname in common_values  and cellname :
        print(type(cellname))
        dfH.at[line, 'resultcellname'] = cellname
        dfH.at[line, 'resultcellnamevalue'] = cellnamevalue
        processed_values.add(cellname)
        line=line+1
      

        dfH=pd.concat([dfH.loc[common_values]],
                      axis=1)


 with pd.ExcelWriter(new_excel_by_user + '.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as user_excel:
  dfH.to_excel(user_excel, sheet_name='High', index=False)
```

**it just adds the new columns but with no values**
[this is the continue of this qustion : this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77520434/how-to-take-intersection-of-multiple-columns-in-excel-and-writing-them-into-a-ne)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
# Checks if 1=2
dfH['resultcellname'] = np.where((dfH['cellname1']==dfH['cellname2']) & (dfH['cellname1value']==dfH['cellname2value']), dfH['cellname1'], dfH['resultcellname'])
dfH['resultcellnamevalue'] = np.where((dfH['cellname1']==dfH['cellname2']) & (dfH['cellname1value']==dfH['cellname2value']), dfH['cellname1value'], dfH['resultcellnamevalue'])
# Checks if 1=3
dfH['resultcellname'] = np.where((dfH['cellname1']==dfH['cellname3']) & (dfH['cellname1value']==dfH['cellname3value']), dfH['cellname1'], dfH['resultcellname'])
dfH['resultcellnamevalue'] = np.where((dfH['cellname1']==dfH['cellname3']) & (dfH['cellname1value']==dfH['cellname3value']), dfH['cellname1value'], dfH['resultcellnamevalue'])
# Checks if 2=3
dfH['resultcellname'] = np.where((dfH['cellname2']==dfH['cellname3']) & (dfH['cellname2value']==dfH['cellname3value']), dfH['cellname2'], dfH['resultcellname'])
dfH['resultcellnamevalue'] = np.where((dfH['cellname2']==dfH['cellname3']) & (dfH['cellname2value']==dfH['cellname3value']), dfH['cellname2value'], dfH['resultcellnamevalue'])
```

Comment: it did not work out

Comment: Then the problem is not in the change of values rows but in the other line of codes. As you did not explain the logic f the value change - I cannot help further

Comment: the codes logic is : i have multiple columns called: cell1,cell2 , ..........     and i want to export the values that are in all columns , cellname1 , cellname2  and....... into a new column

Comment: Please post an example of current data and expected output

Comment: PLEASE CHECKOUT THIS LINK :      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77520434/how-to-take-intersection-of-multiple-columns-in-excel-and-writing-them-into-a-ne

Comment: See updated answer